Cant access user calendar though permission granted, Issue with a Microsoft Graph API
I am trying to book an event in Outlook calendar through Graph API. I have created the application and granted the permission as shown in the screenshot.
The application has both Delegated permission and Application permission

Here is the code that I am using.
import axios from 'axios';
import querystring from 'querystring';

const tenantId = '123456'; // Your Directory (Tenant) ID
const clientId = '-558d64288141'; // Your Application (Client) ID
const clientSecret = 'ZXc8Q~t'; // Your Application Secret Value

async function getAccessToken() {
    const tokenEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
    const params = {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    };

    const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, querystring.stringify(params), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

    return response.data.access_token;
}

async function bookCalendarEvent(accessToken, eventDetails) {
    const endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/schedule@test.com/events'; // Updated endpoint
    
    const response = await axios.post(endpoint, eventDetails, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

    return response.data;
}

export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        // Get access token using client credentials
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();

        // Sample event details
        const eventDetails = {
            subject: 'Meeting with Lambda',
            body: {
                contentType: 'HTML',
                content: 'This is a meeting scheduled by AWS Lambda'
            },
            start: {
                dateTime: '2024-08-27T09:00:00', // Sample start date and time
                timeZone: 'UTC'
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: '2024-08-27T10:00:00', // Sample end date and time
                timeZone: 'UTC'
            },
            attendees: [
                {
                    emailAddress: {
                        address: 'example@domain.com', // Sample attendee email
                        name: 'John Doe'
                    },
                    type: 'required'
                }
            ]
        };

        // Book the calendar event
        const result = await bookCalendarEvent(accessToken, eventDetails);

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Event booked successfully',
                eventId: result.id
            })
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error booking calendar event:', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Error booking event',
                error: error.message
            })
        };
    }
};


But when I run the AWS Lambda I get this error
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Error booking event\",\"error\":\"Request failed with status code 403\"}"
}


So I am not sure what I am doing wrong
Any help
thanks

You need to grant admin consent for calendars.readwrite application type API permission

Check the exclamation next to Calendars.ReadWrite application permission. Once you have Calendars.ReadWrite, you don't need Calendars.Read application permission.

thanks both, @Rukmini user22.Granting admin consent will let me access all the calendars and which I don't want to do.
is there any other way to have access to the single-user calendar?

No application permissions are tenant wide and cannot be restricted to the single user calendar

I agree with @juunas, you need to switch to delegated flows like authorization code flow to have access to only signed-in user's calendar.
I registered one Azure AD application and granted Calendars.ReadWrite permission of Delegated type as below:

Now, I added redirect URI as http://localhost:3000/callback in Web platform of application like this:

In my case, I used below modified code that works with authorization code flow to acquire token and books event in signed-in user calendar:
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let storedAccessToken = '';

const tenantId = 'tenantID';
const clientId = 'appID';
const clientSecret = 'secret';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/callback';

app.get('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const authorizationUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?` + 
    querystring.stringify({
        client_id: clientId,
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        response_mode: 'query',
        scope: 'openid profile offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite',
        state: '12345'
    });

    const { default: open } = await import('open');
    await open(authorizationUrl);

    res.send('Opening Microsoft login page...');
});

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const code = req.query.code;

    async function getAccessToken(code) {
        const tokenEndpoint = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: clientSecret,
            code: code,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            scope: 'openid profile offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite'
        }), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        return response.data.access_token;
    }

    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken(code);
        console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        storedAccessToken = accessToken;
        res.send('Login successful! You can now book an event.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error obtaining access token:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message, error.stack);
        res.status(500).send('Error obtaining access token: ' + error.message);
    }
});

app.get('/book-event', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!storedAccessToken) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User is not authenticated. Please login first.' });
        }

        console.log('Using Stored Access Token:', storedAccessToken);

        const eventDetails = {
            subject: 'Meeting with Lambda',
            body: {
                contentType: 'HTML',
                content: 'This is a meeting scheduled by AWS Lambda'
            },
            start: {
                dateTime: '2024-08-27T09:00:00',
                timeZone: 'UTC'
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: '2024-08-27T10:00:00',
                timeZone: 'UTC'
            },
            attendees: [
                {
                    emailAddress: {
                        address: 'sridevi.maxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
                        name: 'Sridevi'
                    },
                    type: 'required'
                }
            ]
        };

        const calendarEndpoint = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`; 

        const response = await axios.post(calendarEndpoint, eventDetails, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${storedAccessToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        res.json({ message: 'Event booked successfully', eventId: response.data.id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error booking event:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message, error.stack);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error booking event', error: error.message });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Now, run the code and visit http://localhost:3000/login in browser that asks user to login and gives code in address bar after completing authentication like this:

When I ran http://localhost:3000/book-event in browser, it booked the event in signed-in user's calendar successfully like this:

If you try to book event in different user's calendar, it will give 403 error as access will be denied for users other than signed-in user like this:


thanks @Sridevi for the most detailed answer. But My scenario is that I want to build an automated appointment solution that will utilize AWS (Amazon Connect, Amazon Lex, and Lambda).  A user/caller called Amazon Connect (Contact Center)and interacted with LexBot(Voice-Enabled AI Bot), the LexBot will get the Date and time for the appointment. after that, I will run the lambda with the date and time passed in params. the Lambda will call the Graph API to book a calendar event. Do you think this is still possible with delegated permission? This solution will be automated. no user is involved.

If user is not involved, you cannot use delegated permissions. In that case, you need to switch to Application permission, but it grants access to all user's data. You cannot restrict Application permission to single user.

Hi @Amjad Any update on the issue?

Hi @Sridevi, Okay so I managed to get the Application level permission access, But Should I give the Calendars.ReadWrite application level permission Only? Like that would be enough?

Giving application type permission grants access to fetch all user's calendars data.

It's Okayy, So that permission is enough to work with the Calendar now, right?

Yes, it's enough but you need to switch to client credentials flow for service principal authentication....Please click on checkmark beside the answer and upvote if it's helpful for you in any way

@Thanks Sridevi. I accepted the answer. since I am working with the Application level permission now. So might be having questions related to that as well. will  post them here in the comments.

Can you check now?

Since you are using client credentials flow, only application permissions will work. Delegated permissions only work if a user is involved in the token acquisition; which they are not in this case.
For the application permission to work, an app role assignment needs to be granted to the service principal of your app. Pressing the Grant admin consent button will do this (and also add the necessary objects for all the other required permissions you have). You (or someone else) needs to have Application Admin / Cloud Application Admin / Global Admin role.

thanks @juunas. but If I granted the admin consent then this means that I have access to all the user's calendars which I am avoiding.
Can I restrict to only one user after granting admin consent?

I think you need to use delegated permissions for that. It'll be more complicated to implement as the user in question must sign in to your app and consent to the calendar access (or someone with admin access creates the necessary OAuth2PermissionGrant object manually with PowerShell). You can then use the refresh token from that authentication to get tokens as needed to access that user's calendar.
